# how to build a development server

Tags: development

I have some patches I'd like to test on a development server `dev.example.com`.

I plan to take a copy of the files, install them in the web folder for `dev.example.com`, create a new database, and do a find and replace in the SQL export replacing `www.example.com` with `dev.example.com`, and import this into the new database, and alter the local configuration files with the new database connection settings.

Can it be this simple?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the way I did it was to install Virtualbox, install a Linux VM with Apache, PHP and MySQL configured reasonably close to the running environment.

Pulling the live site off involves creating a tarball of everything in the htdoc directory except the image cache, Magento cache, sessions and a compressed mysqldump.

If you get fancy, you can do it with rsync.

Shut the apache server and cron job down, untar the htdoc directory, import the mysqldump, run a script to set file ownership and permissions to match your http server's running needs, import a sql script that changes the base URLs, resets email addresses to your dev address, turns on/off various settings for modules you don't want sending emails, updating external services. Copy over your server specific app/etc/local.xml.

At that point start the http server and cron and you should be live.

If you're proficient with shell scripting, it's all pretty much automatic, not a lot of fiddling. And you're either running Linux in Windows or Linux in Mac for a nice all-around work environment.

Comment: OK: I forgot to add; I'm completely unfamiliar with the Linux command line.